# Solve for x in $ x^2 + y^2 = 1 $ and $ x \pm y = \frac \pi4 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse

Solve for x in  $ x^2+  y^2 = 1 $ and $ x \pm y = \frac \pi4 $

I tried solving this by substitute method. And using the quadratic formula, but that create lots of cases.
The original problem was to solve $ \arcsin x + \arcsin y  = \frac\pi2 $ and $ \sin 2x = \cos2y $.

Comment: Do you want to solve the equations simultaneously or not?

Comment: So, what’s your question? You have equations of the unit circle and two lines that are less than one unit from the origin, so there are four solutions. Finding them doesn’t seem like it should involve all that many cases to consider.

Comment: You have two lines and a circle. Each line meets the circle in two points; finding them will need solving a quadratic equation....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\dfrac\pi2\ge\arcsin x=\arccos y\ge0$$

$\implies\dfrac\pi2>1\ge x, y\ge0$ and $x=\sqrt{1-y^2}$

$0\le2x,2y\le2<\pi$

Again, $\cos2y=\sin2x=\cos\left(\dfrac\pi2-2x\right)$

$$2y=2m\pi\pm\left(\dfrac\pi2-2x\right)$$

$+\implies2(x+y)=2m\pi+\dfrac\pi2$

As $0\le2(x+y)<\pi,\implies m=0\implies \dfrac\pi4= x+y=\sqrt{1-y^2}+y$

$\left(\dfrac\pi4-y\right)^2=1-y^2$

Solve for $y\ge0$

Similarly, $-\implies2(y-x)=2m\pi-\dfrac\pi2$

But $2\ge2(y-x)\ge-2,m=?$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
(x+y)^2+(x-y)^2=2(x^2+y^2)=2
$$
so $(x\mp y)^2=2-(\pi/4)^2$.  This reduces to
\begin{align*}
x\pm y&=\frac\pi4\\
x\mp y&=\varepsilon\sqrt{2-\frac{\pi^2}{16}}
\end{align*}
for $\varepsilon=\pm 1$, independent of the $\pm$ in $x\pm y$.  Can you solve this and get 4 intersection points?